# Most occurrence word in given string

Tags: java

I am trying to find the most occurrence word in a given string. My approach is to work correctly when I directly take an array of string but when I take String and convert it to the array of string than it does not work properly. Please help me to find out the error in my logic.

I used HashMap for this problem.

```java
import java.util.*;


    public class FindingmostOccurrencewordsinGivenString {
        static String OccurreneceofWords(String [] arr)
        {
            HashMap<String,Integer> hs=new HashMap<String,Integer>();

            for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
            {
                if(hs.containsKey(arr[i]))

                hs.put(arr[i],  hs.get(arr[i])+1);
                else

                    hs.put(arr[i], 1);

            }

            Set<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>set=hs.entrySet();
            Integer value=0;
            String key="";
             for(Map.Entry<String, Integer>m:set) 
            {
                if(m.getValue() > value)
                {
                    value=m.getValue();
                    key=m.getKey();
                }
            }
             return key;
        }

        public static void main(String[]args)
        {
            Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
            String str=sc.next();
            String str1[]=str.split("\\s+");
             String arr[] = {  "hey","hi","hi","hello","hi" };//hi
            System.out.println(OccurreneceofWords(str1));




        }
    }
```

Expected output: `hi`

It prints true when

```
String arr[] = {  "hey","hi","hi","hello","hi" };//hi as input.
```

But when input as String and split it into the array of string that time I do not get the correct output which is hi.

Comment: Try `String str=sc.nextLine();`

Comment: To expand on what @JohnnyMopp is suggesting, the documentation for the `Scanner.next()` method states: *Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner.* So by using `next()`, you're only retrieving the first word. `nextLine()`, on the other hand, returns the enter `String` entered by the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I executed your code your logic is correct but there is a single error use using

```
String str=sc.next();
```

Which only reads the first token in the string i.e., 'Hey' .Instead you should use.`

```
String str=sc.nextLine();
```

Comment: Thanks, @JohnyMoop, and Zepher. now my code is running fine.